# the code for project euler #5 doesn't works

Tags: python

the question of project euler #5 is: 
2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

```
result=1
done=False
while not done:
    result+=1
    for x in range(2,21):
        if result%x!=0:
            break
        elif x==20:
            done=True
print(result)
```

but it takes too long time when it runs. well, it seems that this code doesn't work. what is the problem in this code?

Comment: use `print()` inside code to see what is going on in code.

Comment: you may check less numbers - if number is divided by `20` then it has to be divided by `2`, `10`, `4`, `5` too. if is divided by `18` the it has to be divided by `3`, `6` too. This way you can reduce list of numers which you have to check.

Comment: you don't have to check odd numbers because they are not divided by `2`

Comment: if number has to be divided by `20` so you have to check only multiples of `20`

Comment: @TomKarzes but odd number will be not divided by 2 so you can skip it automatically. It can be ie. 17*2 or 17*4 and it is even number. 17*3 is not divided by 2 so you can skip it.

Comment: @furas Sorry, I misunderstood which numbers you were skipping.  You were talking about result candidates, and of course you were correct in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it has to be divided by `20` so you can check only multiples of `20` - this way you have to check a lot less numbers.

If number is divided by `20` so it has to be divided by `2`, `10` (`20=2*10`), `4`, `5` (`20=4*5`) so you don't have to check for `2`,`4`,`5`,`10`. The same way you can eliminate other numbers.

Finally I got list `20`, `19`, `18`, `17`, `16`, `15`, `14`, `13`, `11`

```
import time

start = time.time()

result = 0
done = False

while not done:
    result += 20
    for x in [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 11]:
        if result % x != 0:
            break
    else:
       done = True

end = time.time()

print('result:', result)
print('time in seconds:', end-start)
```

Result:

```
result: 232792560
time in seconds: 6.6211323738098145
```

Comment: For something slower but more reusable, you could do   for num in range(a, b+1):

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is what's referred to as the "Least Common Multiple", or LCM, of the numbers 1 through 20.  This is the union of the multi-sets of prime factors of the those numbers.  For instance, the LCM of 12 and 15 is the union of the multi-sets {2, 2, 3} and {3, 5}, which is {2, 2, 3, 5}, or 60.

If you have a GCD function ("Greatest Common Divisor"), then you can take advantage of the fact that LCM(x, y) = x*y//GCD(x, y).  You can then accumulate the LCM by starting with 1 and adding in the unique factors of each number in turn.

If you're using Python 3, then you can get GCD from `math.gcd`.  For instance, the following will give the answer for 1 through 10:

```
import math
r = 1
for i in range(2, 11):
    r = r * i // math.gcd(r, i)

print(r)
```

This gives `2520` as expected.  For 1 through 20, just do:

```
import math
r = 1
for i in range(2, 21):
    r = r * i // math.gcd(r, i)

print(r)
```

This gives `232792560`.

Both computations are essentially instantaneous.

Update:  You can actually squeeze a tiny bit more out of this by replacing the loop body with:

```
    r *= i // math.gcd(r, i)
```

This works since `i` is a multiple of `math.gcd(r, i)`.  By dividing before multiplying, the numbers involved in the computation are slightly smaller.

Comment: I checked time: `time in seconds: 0.0001163482666015625` :)

Comment: @furas Oh, nice!